# getElementById in temporary document is not function

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i have problem when i want to get id in li element and stored in temporary document.
this is my javascript code.

```
var tempNode = document.createElement("div"); //creating element for storing response
    tempNode.innerHTML=ajaxhttp.responseText;
var nodes = tempNode.getElementsByTagName("div");
```

ajaxhttp.responseText equals to

```
<div id="side">
    .....    
    parent
    parent

</div>
        </li>
        <li id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">       <h2 class="widgettitle">fdfs</h2>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="example.com2011/11/16/43422/" title="fdsdfしい！&nbsp;モsdf&nbsp;モバイルdsf</a></li>
                                    </ul>
        </li>



<li id="text-7" class="widget widget_text">         
......
</div>
```

i'm sory if too much but that is my problem.
when i try to loop and get id with this code

```
for (n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
 console.log(tempNode.getElementById('recent-posts-3'));
}
```

the error is not function.and when i try to `document.getElementById('recent-posts-3');` the error is same. how i can  fixed this problem?

note :

if in my tempNode only this

```
<li id="recent-posts-3" class="widget widget_recent_entries">       <h2 class="widgettitle">fdfs</h2>
    <ul>
            <li><a href="example.com2011/11/16/43422/" title="fdsdfしい！&nbsp;モsdf&nbsp;モバイルdsf</a></li>
                                </ul>
    </li>
```

that's work. but not in my case i want to all element.
2.and i'm not use jquery i want pure javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getElementById is a method of document, but you use it on a element

You may use element.querySelector() instead:

```
tempNode.querySelector('li[id="recent-posts-3"]')
```

Comment: +1 for getting the issue right, but the solution is not great. The *querySelector* method is only available in recent browsers, at the very least it should be feature tested and an alternative offered.

Comment: so how i can suport in all browser . you true that is my want.thanks for your answer...by the way how i can find reference for your answer..

Comment: ah viola. that is my want ... thanks for your suggest with library.

Answer (score 1):

An ID must be unique within the entire document, and as such there is no reason for the function `getElementById` to be available for each node. Instead, just use `document.getElementById`; it will return the element with that ID (of which there should only be one).

To do this, you do need to append the `div` to the `body` first:

```
tempNode.style.display = "none"; // to visually still hide it

document.body.appendChild(tempNode);

var elem = document.getElementById("recent-posts-3");
```

Comment: I guess getElementById is only available in document because it needs a DTD to know what is defined as an ID-attribute

Comment: thanks pimvdb your answer is briliant but when i try document.body.appendChild(tempNode);
any double tag html and meta and other element . because document.body in my case is available html page.and if i run can make broken css.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this code in Chrome , Firefox 7, IE 8

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<a id="myId">AAAA</a>';
var a = div.getElementById('myId');
alert(a.id);
```

Chrome: alerts myId

Firefox: alerts myId

IE: gives Object doesn't support this property or method error

So it seems that in IE 8 at least when you create with `document.createElement`(EDIT: and when you retrieve an element) it has only one method `nextSibling`, while in Chrome and Firefox the entire method list is added

So the only cross browser solution I can think of right now is to add the element to a hidden div in the document and then execute the getElementById

SEE: http://jsfiddle.net/zMkfr/

Comment: Interesting; on Chrome I get `TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getElementById'`

Comment: thanks for your answer.in your case is true. but in my case not singgle parent in my case much parent.